# Are questions about very early computing devices on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am thinking about the machines envisaged and built by Charles Babbage and contemporaries. These are general-purpose computing devices which are not current.

Are questions about these systems on-topic?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say yes they are.

There are a number of efforts in museums around the world to (re)create the likes of ENIAC, Colossus, the Babbage Difference Engine and others.  Indeed we already have a question about ENIAC.

Also, museums are working on emulators so as to educate people as to the workings of these old machines.  This too should be on-topic in my opinion.

As to how far back you can go and still call a machine on-topic, that is open to debate.  The Antikythera mechanism or the Stonehenge Aubrey Holes are likely to be considered off-topic.